# VBA Function to write daily cases for each headcount according to dates

Tags: excel, vba

[image: ![enter image description here]

I need to create a function that, starting from table E3:L7, writes values in row 14 (highlighted in yellow).

*It must be considered that line 12 is filled in by another separate function, not the subject of this request (in-depth analysis it represents working days between dates in column E).*

The objective is to write, in each cell of row 14, the following ratio: "H/J/K" to provide information on the daily cases to be performed per person.
For 3rd row: **58.5/10/1 = 5.85** to write in the cells between E14 and K14.

For the following lines (4th, to this ratio I must add the previous ratio (see L14:N14), i.e.: **19.5/3/1 + 5.85** of the ratio of the previous line = **12.35** to write in the cells between L14 and N14.

Note that in the table I could possibly write also in the following lines (5, 6, 7), not filled in the example.

The follow code doesn't work for me (please don't consider it, it has the wrong points). It makes a mistake in the calculation I would like to do and gives me a runtime error if there are rows it wants in the starting table

```
Sub funcX()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim SearchDate As Variant
Dim StartDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date
Dim Result As Double
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")

ws.Range("E14", ws.Cells(14, ws.Columns.Count)).ClearContents

For i = 5 To ws.Cells(11, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    SearchDate = ws.Cells(11, i).Value
    
    If IsDate(SearchDate) Then
        For j = 3 To 7
            StartDate = ws.Cells(j, 5).Value

            If j = 7 Then
                EndDate = ws.Cells(13, 4).Value
            Else
                EndDate = ws.Cells(j + 1, 5).Value
            End If
            
            If SearchDate >= StartDate And SearchDate < EndDate Then
                Result = ws.Cells(j, 8).Value / ws.Cells(j, 11).Value / ws.Cells(j, 10).Value
                ws.Cells(14, i).Value = Result
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

I hope you can help me!!! A thousand thanks!

Comment: SO is not a code writing service.  Please post the code you have tried clearly indicating the line causing a problem.

Comment: My code (now in the question) is wrong, It doesn't do what I want.

Comment: See my edits on your previous post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Calculate ratio and store in an array `arrRes`
- Populate row 14 base on the date in row 12

```vb
Sub funcX()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim SearchDate As Variant
    Dim StartDate As Date
    Dim EndDate As Date
    Dim Result As Double
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim arrData, arrRes()
    Const DATA_RANGE = "F4:M8"
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
    arrData = ws.Range(DATA_RANGE).Value
    ReDim arrRes(1 To UBound(arrData), 1 To 2)
    Dim k As Long: k = 0
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrData)
        If Len(arrData(i, 1) > 0) And IsDate(arrData(i, 1)) Then
            k = k + 1
            arrRes(k, 1) = arrData(i, 1)
            If Len(arrData(i, 4)) > 0 Then
                arrRes(k, 2) = arrData(i, 4) / arrData(i, 6) / arrData(i, 7)
                If k > 1 Then arrRes(k, 2) = arrRes(k, 2) + arrRes(k - 1, 2)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    ws.Range("E14", ws.Cells(14, ws.Columns.Count)).ClearContents
    For i = 6 To ws.Cells(12, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        SearchDate = ws.Cells(12, i).Value
        If IsDate(SearchDate) Then
            For j = 1 To k - 1
                If SearchDate >= arrRes(j, 1) And SearchDate <= arrRes(j + 1, 1) Then
                    ws.Cells(14, i).Value = arrRes(j, 2)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much Taller! It Works!!! Except that I had to change the references because they were wrong in the image posted in the question. I proceeded to modify them and change your code slightly.